# get name of all resources from helm release

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I want get name of resources from helm release. But I don't understand how.

I don't find anything

```
helm get all RELEASE_NAME --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{end}}'
```

Answer (score 2):

`helm get all` has a somewhat constrained set of options for its `--template` option; it gets passed in a single `.Release` object, and the set of created Kubernetes options is stored in text in a `.Release.Manifest` field.

```sh
helm get all RELEASE_NAME --template '{{ .Release.Manifest }}'
# returns the manifest as a string
```

There's a dedicated [`helm get manifest`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_manifest/) subcommand that returns the manifest as YAML.

Once you have the YAML, you need to extract the resource names from it.  One approach is to use a tool like [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) that can do generic queries over YAML:

```
helm get manifest RELEASE_NAME | yq eval '.metadata.name' -
```

Comment: thx, but i wanted to understand how to do it using --template

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: yq eval '.metadata.name' - don't work :( yq: error: argument files: can't open '.metadata.name'

Comment: Do you have the `-` as the last argument?  Also, what `yq --version`?  It looks like the [v3 vs. v4 syntax](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/upgrading-from-v3) is substantially different.

Comment: Version yq 2.12.2

Comment: To extract the kind of resource too, I use this:

`helm get manifest -n NAMESPACE RELEASE_NAME | yq '[.kind, .metadata.name] | join("/")'`